# ReportViewer grouping header in report header section?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

[image]

Hi, I'm working on a report which uses reportviewer in VS2010.

It is an invoice report. It has some **accounts** in the system, for each **account**, it has some **orders**. Now, in each month, we need to send the invoice to each account.

In the report, at the top, we need to list **"Bill To"** `(the address for each account)` and **"Invoice#"**, for each **account**, it is **different**, and it is **continouous**. Then, at the center, it should list the details of the orders for this account. Obviously, each account should have an invoice.

See the attached screen shot. I used grouping and created the invoice shown in screen shot.

But, it has a problem. The **"Account address"**, **"Terms"**, and **"Invoice #"**, I could not put them in the grouping (those are the same within the group). Thus, for different groups, they are shown as the same values, although in the rdlc file, I put their fields there.

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

One possibility is: instead of creating the invoice for all accounts in one report (i.e. 20 pages, each page is an invoice for an account), create a report for each invoice for each account (so total 20 files), then print the invoice directly. This will work since we can manipulate all the data, and use reportviewer parameters for Account Address, Terms, ...

However, it means we could not browse the reports before print (withint the software). Any suggestions?

thanks

reader

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is , since for each account there is an address, invoice# and  invoice details or **orders** in your case,
 
So what you can do is :

**EDIT :**  Let me go in some detailed fashion ! (Please zoom in to see the image details clearly)

1.Create a new report and add a Tablix to it 

`--Tablix has the property , it can iterate through your data`
and create dataset which will get data for Account address, invoice, and Terms. Then :
 [image]

if you are not able to view the image properly ..[here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzg8dbh1CrN9bXRkVnB1NDRtSGM/edit) is the same presented for you 

 This is the way I did my reports with similar requirements...[sub-reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would ease the tasks to a much extent .. 
 
 p.s:

- **Edit:** No need to go for a Header.. as you say in your subject of question.
  jus the main report and a sub-report should do what you need !
- I jus saw yours is `crystal report`.. but the concept is over all the same

Comment: thanks for reply. I used crystal-report as tag simply because I thought more people will see the question. it is for ms reporting. the issue I have is: I have to put the address/invoice#/terms in header which caused the problem. The solution I have now is: create the report for each account, export pdf file automatically, then merge pdf into one big pdf. it works fine, but I would think we should be able to do it in reporting too.

Comment: @urlreader I have edited and improved my answer.. there's actaully no need to go for separate reports .. check my edits..

Comment: thanks again. I think in most cases, this will work. However, to my special case, each account will need to generate a separated pdf file, so can be emailed separately. but then, manager want to check all the pdf in one file. thanks again.